# Mikrotik - 2 Static IP For WAN Only one Ip Worked

Tags: ip, routing, adsl, mikrotik-routeros

I have `Mikrotik Router board` I have 2 ADSL internet with 2 Valid IP that I connect to adsl with pope connection
My config is

```
pppoe-WAN1 IN ether1
pppoe-WAN2 in ether2
Defaul route is ether1
```

When I want to ping my ip's from my home I ping Ip of WAN1 but can not ping Ip of WAN2
If I change default route to WAN2 then can ping IP of wan 2 but can not ping ip of WAN1
I wat to ping all IP every time

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the default gateway; router receives ping from WAN2 but sends the reply-back to WAN1. You need to add mangle rules and routes to send back data to the same interface you received them.

Check the examples given in manual:
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:PCC